# TSQL work out VAT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, calculated-field

I have a query which give me the Gross Amount for a Repair-

That amount is 10.88.

I also pull back the VAT rate that corresponds to the Repair.

In this instance it is 20.00. (20%) But this could in theory be any rate, for example 17.50.

These two fields are called "GrossAmount" and "VatRate".

What I need to try and do is work out the Vat and the Net Amount.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `work out the Vat and the Net amount`?  Please show some sample data to illustrate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get (from tables) the GROSS and the VAT rate, you could phrase something like:

```
  SELECT GROSS, VAT_RATE , (GROSS * VAT_RATE) AS VAT , (GROSS + VAT) AS NET
    FROM ....
```

There are, of course, other options depending on how and where from you get the data.

Comment: In your NET calculation you will not be able to reference VAT, you would need to use GROSS * VAT_RATE again

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor of course!!! You are absolutely right. Thanks for the good catch.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help

Comment: I'm lost. I have a material GROSS VALUE of 10.88. Using a VAT Calculator online gives me 1.81 as the VAT and 9.07 as the NET so those are the two figures I am trying to create. If I take GROSS * VAT_RATE in my data that is  10.88*20.00 which gives me 217.600? That's not right is it?

Comment: Dear @killedbill, if VAT = 20, then GROSS * VAR_RATE **/ 100** because **20** means 20 percent. In your example, the GROSS VALUE **includes** the VAR, right (i.e. 9.07 * 1.2 = 10.88)? In any case, I believe that the method/idea is quite clear and you can manage from here.